# The Technology Behind Animoji by Apple

Tags: image-processing

Last year Apple releases their new phone Apple X that has an exciting feature called Animoji. I am so fascinated by this technology that I really want to make my own version of it. But the problem is I am really new in image processing stuff and I've no idea about the technology behind Animoji. So what is the technology behind the Applle Animoji and what sort of knowledge should I have if I want to build my own version of Animoji from scratch?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1838/

Comment: @endolith, I haven't got any clue from your link.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm joking that it's probably based on neural networks, and so nobody really knows how it works.  We can dissect the networks and find out what they're doing at certain layers, but that's about it. More deterministic facial tracking algorithms were used in the past, but it's my understanding that everything is neural networks now because they work better. I could be wrong.

Comment: I would be watching their research blog very closely ;)

Comment: @jojek, would you please share the link of their research blog.

Comment: it basically depends on two technologies one of which is augmented reality and the other is the face tracking technology that scans 50 of your facial muscles and starts tracking them then using the augmented reality it translates it into a new feature may be an emoji or whatever its programmed to do

Answer (score 3):

It's more like a soft answer (I am happy to update it later), but Alex Acero explained the technology behind aniomoji on this years ICASSP 2018. [Here is the link](https://youtu.be/LpgXi6MT-Gw?t=48m41s). Basically, they are using so-called Blendshapes to estimate the positions of the muscles and then they are mapping them to the actual animoji model.

Comment: I attended this talk, and I should say that I was p*ssed by the fuzz around this.

Comment: Personally, I hated the last 20 minutes. It was like a pitch for Apple.

Comment: Same, my mind switched off, and I spent the rest of the time reading the abstract book.